# How to build React-Native with react-native-video on CI?

Tags: android, react-native, circleci

I'm using `react-native@0.42.0` with `react-native-video@1.0.0` and I cannot build the app on Android with CircleCi.

When I use this config:

```
dependencies:
  pre:
    - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "tools,platform-tools,android-23"
    - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "build-tools-23.0.1"
```

I get this error on `cd android && ./gradlew app:dependencies`:

```
> A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-video'.
  > The SDK Build Tools revision (23.0.1) is too low for project ':react-native-video'. Minimum required is 25.0.0
```

When I use this config:

```
echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "build-tools-25.0.0"
```

I get this error on `cd android && ./gradlew app:dependencies`:

```
> A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-video'.
  > You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
    [Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.1].
    Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
    Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
```

When I use this config:

```
echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "build-tools-25.0.0,build-tools-23.0.1"
```

I get this error on `cd android && ./gradlew app:dependencies`:

```
> A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-video'.
  > The SDK Build Tools revision (23.0.1) is too low for project ':react-native-video'. Minimum required is 25.0.0
```

I don't understand the error message when I specify `23.0.1` AND `25.0.0`. In the logs everything seems to be correct.

Thanks you

Comment: Finally I create a new project and everything works fine!